# Ruby datetime format in ActiveRecord database

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I need to save datetime attribute in this format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:SS. I have a datetime field in the database:

`schema.rb:`

```
create_table "stats", force: :cascade do |t|
  ...
  t.datetime "check_time"
end
```

The data in params looks like this:

`{"check_time"=>"2018-01-02 04:57"}`

however it gets saved as 2018-01-02 04:43:00 UTC in the database:
[image]

```
Stat.last.check_time #=> check_time: "2018-01-02 04:43:00"
```

(so it has seconds on the end)

Then in my `"/status"` endpoint I return the stats as JSON:

```
get '/status' do
  { stats: Stat.last }.to_json
end
```

and check_time then looks like this:

`"check_time":"2018-01-02T04:43:00.000Z"`

What's going on here? Am I missing anything here? Do I have an incorrect data type field in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord casts the column to a DateTime object, as extended by ActiveSupport (baked into Rails)

What you're looking for is `strftime` or `to_formatted_s` (aliased to `to_s`.)

Refer here http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-to_formatted_s and http://foragoodstrftime.com

There's no need to mess with ActiveRecord writer methods and you should never do that unless you really know what you're doing. You don't need to save it to the database in a particular format — a non-standard format at that — just format it when you need to and keep all the goodies of your database's datetime-esque column.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are a genius! I have updated my stats check_time to `check_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` and it worked like a charm! My output looks now like this: `{ stats: { hostname: stat.hostname, cpu: stat.cpu, ram: stat.ram, disk: stat.disk,
              check_time: stat.check_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') } }.to_json`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DateTime.now.to_s(:db)
```

Refer here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-to_formatted_s

or

In your model, create a setter method, where "check_time" is your database field.

```
def my_date=(val)
  DateTime.strptime(val, '%Y%m%d;%H%M%S').strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S') if val.present?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Timestamps (AKA "`datetime`") will have much higher resolution that minutes inside the database so you can't really store `2018-01-02 04:57` as a timestamp.

The output you're seeing:

```
2018-01-02T04:43:00.000Z
```

is the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) representation of the timestamp along with all the extra precision and timezone offset ("Z" means "zero" as Rails likes to use UTC inside the database).

Being able to manipulate the values using the database's date and time functions will probably be useful at some point so a timestamp/datetime is what you want to use inside the database. If you really want `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm` as your output format then adjust the output format at the end of your application with `strftime`:

```
stat.check_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```